# Why is tomcat-maven-plugin trying to deploy to the wrong URL?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I am creating a dummy maven project with two modules, and I have included a general pom.xml file.  I am able to build from the root pom.xml file and run all the tests but when it comes to deploying the files to Tomcat, it falls down.  The plugin I have is:

```
<build>
    <finalName>dummy</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8090/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/dummy</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

However, when I run the build it uses the default configuration values and I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&war= -> [Help 1]

Does anyone know how I can get the plugin to be using my config?

More output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [webapp] in [C:\Websites\www.dummy.app\webapp\target\webapp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Websites\www.dummy.app\webapp\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [15 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Websites\www.dummy.app\webapp\target\webapp.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ webapp <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/webapp
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] my-app ............................................ SUCCESS [4.747s]
[INFO] webapp ............................................ FAILURE [3.313s]
[INFO] dummy ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.376s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 23 22:46:11 GMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&war= -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :webapp
```

Thanks

Comment: Your manager URL looks weird - why is there a `/text` in the name? Also, have you verified Tomcat is properly configured to run on port 8080 and that the manager app is installed?

Comment: For deployment on Tomcat7, the URL needs to end in /html or /text.  I think it should be /text but I havent gotten that far to test :).  Tomcat is running on the right port because http://127.0.0.1:8090/manager/html resolves to the Tomcat Manager

Comment: Could you post the relevant console log running it in debug mode (`mvn -X`)?

Comment: More output added above - thanks

Comment: Have you tried the 2.0-SNAPSHOT version of the tomcat-plugin? 
http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 3):

```
<properties>
   <maven.tomcat.url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</maven.tomcat.url>
</properties>
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [version 2.0-beta-1](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/index.html) of the plugin.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-68

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem.Here is how I resolved.Though this is a late answer,I think this answer will hold true even today.

I am using tomcat7.The tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1 defaults to tomcat deployment url  `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` , but for **tomcat 7** the url has changed to `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`.

**Step 1 : Find the url & role for tomcat to deploy war files.**

I found that by manually going to

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

The url used to deploy is : **/text** , so maven should use **`http://localhost:8080/manager/text`**
The role for this url is "**manager-script**"

```
   <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Text Manager interface (for scripts)</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/text/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>manager-script</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

**Step 2 : Configure tomcat credentials for the role**

So now we have found the URL to deploy the war and the role.If you havent configured tomcat users.Below is how to add the roles to apache-tomcat-7.0.41\conf\tomcat-users.xml.

```
<tomcat-users>

  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

**Step 3: Configure tomcat-maven-plugin in pom.xml to use the tomcat url for deployment.**

Now we need to configure tomcat-maven-plugin to use these.Below is my plugin configuration in the pom.xml.This will override the tomcat-maven-plugin's default tomcat deploy url.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <server>mytomcatserver</server>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Step 4 : Configure maven's settings.xml for the tomcat url credentials.**

Now for the maven plugin to deploy the war file to tomcat , it needs the username & password
for your tomcat server.
Find out settings.xml of maven is located ( mine was at apache-maven-3.2.3\conf ) and apply the below config to the

```
<servers>
  <server>
      <id>mytomcatserver</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**Step 5 : Moment of truth**

Start tomcat.

mvn package  ( war file created )

mvn tomcat:deploy ( watch tomcat console for the war deployment )

Your webapp will be available at `http://localhost:8080/{context}`