# Maven auto deployment to tomcat6 failure, deploying to incorrect URL

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

I'm trying auto deploy war file to apache-tomcat-server(**6.0.33**) using tomcat-maven-plugin6, but on tomcat:deploy command, maven(3.5.1/1.5.1.xxx EclipseIDE-embedded) is trying to install to incorrect URL (localhost:8080/webapplication), I have seen similar Q&A **here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962381/why-is-tomcat-maven-plugin-trying-to-deploy-to-the-wrong-url),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338248/tomcat-maven-plugin-401-error))** but it's answers does not solved my problem. Please find more details below.

**Settings.xml**

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>localhost</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId> org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
        <!-- <username>usr</username> <password>pwd</password> -->
        <server>localhost</server>
        <path>/datatest</path>
        <warFile>target/service-manager.war</warFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Maven Console:**

```
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ service-manager <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ service-manager ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/service-manager  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Data manager ...................................... SUCCESS [  7.454 s]
[INFO] Business Manager .................................. SUCCESS [  0.109 s]
[INFO] Core module ....................................... SUCCESS [  6.699 s]
[INFO] Booter Application ................................ SUCCESS [  1.016 s]
[INFO] Booter Service Webapp ............................. FAILURE [ 33.289 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 49.099 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-09T16:09:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project service-manager: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fservice-manager&war= -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project service-manager: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
```

Comment: Setting both the `<warFile>` and the `<path>` probably confuses the plugin and causes it to ignore the `<path>` mention (I agree - it shouldn't really have been coded that way). It looks like the `war` in your case is in the default location with the default name, so try removing the `<warFile>` mention and see if it causes the `<path>` setting to not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **url** should be `http://localhost:8080/manager/text` (you missed the /text).

Comment: I think for tomcat6:  http://localhost:8080/manager and for tomcat7: http://localhost:8080/manager/text is the URL

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - /manager/text is the url for tomcat7. Sorry for that. I think @mystarrocks 's answer could be the right one - try NOT to use path and warFile in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same behaviour and maybe you're trying to invoke the **wrong maven goal**.

First be sure your username and password are informed acoording to Tomcat `conf/tomcat-users.xml` configuration.

Second, if you are deploying on Tomcat 6, try using `tomcat6:deploy` or `tomcat6:redeploy` goal (instead of tomcat:deploy). Worked for me.

Some advices:

- If it's not a requirement, better use last stable version of the plugin 2.2 http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/
- I've never used `warFile` property, are you using it because there are several wars on target folder? If not, isn't necessary specify it.